# How to change the value of a variable in android studio?

Tags: android

i have to change the value of a variable when a button is pressed.I want to write that when you press this button the variable a change his value to 2 from 1(for example). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to design the layout for this activity with name layout_name and a button with id or name butChange. And inside the activity class you can do something like this:

```
Button change;
int a = 1;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);

change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butChange); //parsing the XMLtype 'butChange' to'change'.
change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         a=2;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry...is very simple..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl    Use this link, it can make you work easier.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to declare the variable global in the Activity/Fragment class. Then you can access it from everywhere in the class and change value.

For example :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  //Here you can declare globally
  private int myVar = 0;

  public void myMethod(){
    //You can modify the global var
    myVar = 1;
  }

}
```